# Database: Design customer orders

Tags: database, sqlite

I am currently creating an Android application which should use SQLite database. In my case, I need to strore "product type", "bill" and "list of all purchased products"

**Bill:**

```
id
customer
data -> link to list of all purchased products
price
```

**Product types:**

```
id
name
price
```

My question is: One customer could have more products connected to one bill. How to design it? Is using a Use a one row for every bills:

```
id
bill_id
product
```

or rather insert more products into one row and then parse it in my application? I suppose, there is a better solution that these mine. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said in your question, "One customer could have more products connected to one bill."

Another way of saying this is, one customer can have 0 or more bills, and one bill can have 1 or more products.

After rephrasing your statement, the [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) becomes more obvious.

```
Customer
--------
Customer ID
Customer Name
...

Bill
----
Bill ID
Customer ID
Bill Time Stamp

Bill-Product
------------
Bill ID
Product ID

Product
-------
Product ID
Product Name
Product Price
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To design customer order with bill we can design it as below:

This schema having basics attributes we can add more as per requirements.

**Customers Table**

id PK

full_name

address

phone

**MenuItems Table**

id PK

item_name

item_description

item_price

**Order Table**

id PK

customer_id FK

order_date

**OrderDetails Table**

id PK

order_id FK

menu_item_id fk

quantity

**Bill Table**

id PK

order_id FK

amount

bill_date